# Is any application for MongoDB browser in ubuntu 16.04 32 bit processor

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, umongo

I trying to install Mongo DB browser for Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit version but none of application installing to the machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about robo3t, you can download the .tar.gz file for Linux (https://robomongo.org/download), unpack it and run the bin/robo3t executable.
You don't even need to install it.

Comment: for 32 bit processor it is not supporting error is invalid encoding